# How to copy layer from one Photoshop document to another but on specific position of other layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I will try to be more specific.
I have opened document with 20 layers and another document with 1 layer. How to copy this one layer in document with 20 layers on the exactly same position of layer 10 for example? Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to do this for automation? you need write ascript.
If not, you can find the exact position of each layer by

1. Select the layer pressing Ctrl + T.
2. Under the Photoshop menu you can find the X & Y position of layer.

So... First select 10 layer and find its position (by pressing Ctrl + T).
Next you have to move the other layer to destination file and change its position by pressing Ctrl + T and Changing the X & Y values.

I don't know what is your purpose exactly but there are lots of ways to do it. for example another way is ....

1. Copy first image.
2. Go to next psd file
3. press Ctrl and click on thumbnail of layer 10 to make a selection around layer 10
4. Press Ctrl + V or Alt +Ctrl +Shift + V to paste image in selection location.